# Postgres is not taking System Resources

Tags: database, linux, postgresql, linux-kernel

I am restoring my database to  my new database in postgresql in linux 2.6.18 kernel. 
My problem is restoring does not happen  quickly, And even system has 90 % free resources. 
It does not consume all  the resource not doing the things as fastest. what can be issue ?
How can overcome this issue.. Please help me out of this problem.

Note : 
I  have used following things for pg_dump and restoring.

```
pg_dump -Fc -h 192.168.12.165 -d mydb -U mydb -f  log.sql.tar.gz
pg_restore -Fc -h 192.168.12.165 -d mydb -U mydb log.sql.tar.gz
```

Why this system is not allowing postgres to consume all available memory and cpu  resources ?

Comment: Have you tried the -j switch with pg_restore?  Basically a lot of restoring tends to be done in sequence, so you can only really use one core, and are limited by the disk io bandwidth a lot.  This is true for most databases.  The -j switch will allow postgresql to parallelize a few more things like index creation, but note that if your system has limited IO or CPU capacity it may actually make a restore slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres uses only very little system resources out of the box, so you will have to adjust the configuration settings to allow it to consume more.

There is a page on the wiki that gives you some hints on how to speed up the restoring of the database: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Bulk_Loading_and_Restores